# How to use data obtained from a form in Django form?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form in Django using Django form. 
I need two types of forms.

1. A form that collect data from user, do some calculations and show the results to user without saving the data to database. I want to show the result to user once he/she press button (calculate) next to it not in different page.
2. A form that collect data from user, look for it in a column in google sheet, and if it's unique, add it to the column otherwise inform the user a warning that the data is not unique.

Thanks

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Both of this should be done in the browser with JS so django or python does not have to do anything with it. JQuery might also help with this.

Comment: I don't know how to work with JS nor JQuey, 
I have written a package in python with many math equations to calculate something. What I need is a user, input a value in a form, immediately show the results beside it. What I was expecting is that, I get the value that user has inputted, pass it to module in I've written in python in server side, it calculate and outputs a value, then I pass this value to html template and show it to the user. Am I right?

Comment: Start by writing it in a way that the user submits the form (like any normal django form), you process it in your view, do the calculation, and return the same page with the calculated values (render the template). That way you know everything is working as expected. Then once that works, refactor to make your form submit the data using AJAX and your view to just return the calculation results in JSON. Your AJAX success handler can then insert the results in the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX and javascript to achieve this, but I suggest doing this only via javascript. This means you will have to rewrite the math in JS and output it directly in the element.

Please let me know if you need any help :)

Jasper

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
 It's not a single equation. I have written a bunch of modules in python which I want to show their output in a website. I used to had a wordpress website and after inquiry I found python code can't be integrated with php. So, I created a website using Django, I tried to create a form that collect data and render it in server side using my python code.  If I want to rewrite all python codes in javascript, It takes lots of time although I guess I can use it in php website, too. I need to know isn't there any way that this can be handled using python and django?

Comment: I also used many libraries in python to solve that equations that I'm not sure if it's possible to do in JS

Comment: Hey Majid. This could be done if you create an api to return the data. Look into JavaScript fetch or AJAX. This way you can do a request to your api and do the equations on the python side. then return the answers and render them via JS.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing it in a way that the user submits the form (like any normal django form), you process it in your view, do the calculation, and return the same page with the calculated values (render the template). That way you know everything is working as expected, using just Django/python.

Then once that works, refactor to make your form submit the data using AJAX and your view to just return the calculation results in JSON. Your AJAX success handler can then insert the results in the current page.

The reason I suggest you do this in 2 steps is that you're a beginner with javascript, so if you directly try to build this with AJAX, and you're not getting the results you expect, it's difficult to understand where things go wrong.